# How to get Spring Boot to show Thymeleaf parse errors in browser

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Whenever I have a syntax error in my thymeleaf template I will recieve an error message in the browser that says

`An error happened during template parsing (template: "xxx")`

and I need to go to the console and sift through all the logs to find the specific error.

Is there a way to tell spring boot to show me the exact error in the browser when this happens?